# Azure build Pipeline gets failed. Unable to find a dependent package

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am building the project through the Azure pipeline. The project is building locally but failing in the pipeline.
.

> Error:- The type or namespace name 'CommonModules' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I am creating a web API application. I have used class library projects. I am passing the reference to a class library into another class library. I have set up the project dependencies too. It is building successfully in VS 2019. But when the build gets triggered in the Azure pipeline, it is showing error 'The type or namespace name 'CommonModules' could not be found'. Here CommonModules is the class library that is used as a reference in another class library. How to solve

Comment: Does anyone have any idea regarding it?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure build Pipeline gets failed. Unable to find a dependent package

According to the error message:

```
'The type or namespace name 'CommonModules' could not be found'
```

It seems that you just build the reference library instead of the solution file.

To resolve this issue, try to build the solution file .sln with `Visual Studio build task`:

[image]

**Note:** If it not help you, please share more info about this issue, like the project structure and the specific configuration of your visual studio build task.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have checked and I am building the solution file. So, it didn't help

Comment: Actually, here CommonModule(suppose A) is a library that is used as a reference in another class library(suppose B). The error I am getting is that the type or namespace  A could not be found in class library B. In the project I have used the reference of A in project B

Comment: ProjectA and Project B are in the same solution and in the same repo? And if you are using the project reference not the nuget package?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the issue by adding ProjectRefernce in csproj file.
Actually earlier I am adding a reference of the file locally. Azure deployment is not able to find it. To host our solution, one needs to add ProjectRefernce